# Fedora : fail2ban will not show up in iptables -L

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, fail2ban

I have Fedora installed on one of our servers and installed `fail2ban` on it. In `jail.conf`, I have added the below text, but `iptables -L` still wont show the fail2ban-ssh. Am I missing something?

Text added to `jail.conf`:

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

*Update*

Current file:

[image]

changing to sshd.conf gives following error :

```
2018-02-22 08:45:14,029 fail2ban.actions        [10124]: ERROR   Failed to start jail 'ssh' action 'firewallcmd-ipset': Error starting action
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misconfiguration of your default banaction. Here's how I would try to fix it:

1. Edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` file and change the line

   ```
   banaction = firewallcmd-ipset
   ```

   to

   ```
   banaction = iptables-allports
   ```

   If you reload your fail2ban-client it should start correctly now, but …

As I suggest not to change the default jail.conf file at all, I would instead create a separate jail.local config file and add custom options in there.

2. Edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` file and remove the manually added [ssh] jail section.
3. Create separate config file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` and in this file add:

   ```
   [DEFAULT]
   banaction = iptables-allports

   [sshd]
   enabled = true
   ```

   That's it.
   This will set the correct banaction and also activate the default sshd jail (as seen in jail.conf). This sshd jail will look for a filter file `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` because we did not specify any other filter file. And, as long as you don't have any special configuration, the default sshd.conf filter file should work fine.

Comment: This worked nicely with jail.local. On a side note, any ideas why whenever I try service fail2ban restart, it fails, but when I run /usr/bin/fail2ban-client start/stop, it works fine. Thanks. :D

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Regarding your restart issue, I could only guess what might cause this without any further information. May I ask you to create separate question for this issue and provide more information/error messages/log/config?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check is your fail2ban service is running.
If it is, check if you have a filter ssh.conf in  filter.d dir.

You can activate the log for fail2ban in fail2ban.conf : 
loglevel = DEBUG
logtarget = path_to_log

restart fail2ban after editing.
And there are always the potability nothing was baned cos no one tried to acsses more than 6 times whit the wrong Permissions.

Comment: I don't have ssh.conf in filter. but I have sshd-aggressive.conf, sshd.conf and ssdh-ddos.conf. Fail2ban is running. Thank you.

Comment: then try  [ sshd.conf ] Or create ssh filter. depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I reinstalled fail2ban without any changes, no luck. Any way to reconfigure fail2ban entirely? Please check updated post. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Is your firewalld service running?

Answer (score 1):

Reviving an old thread to say I just ran into this myself. Fail2ban seems to have switched to a just-in-time mechanism, where it does not create the chain and jump rules until an IP gets banned.

Manually ban an IP (`fail2ban-client set recidive banip 1.2.3.4`) and the chain as well as the jump rule gets added to iptables.

Comment: thank you @Jayfrown. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I could feel the additional grey hairs growing prior to reading your answer.